# MediaRecorder state turns to 'inactive' automatically in Anular app

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

I am using *MediaRecorder* to record audio in an angular application. The problem I'm facing is, when I start recording the MediaRecorder state is 'Recording', when I try to stop recording, the state is already in 'inactive' state. Because of this getting the following error `ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'stop' on 'MediaRecorder': The MediaRecorder's state is 'inactive'.` Here is the code I've written

```
const audioOptions = {
      video: false,
      audio: {
        echoCancellation: true,
        noiseSuppression: true,
        sampleRate: 16000
      }
    };
    try {
      // @ts-ignore
      let audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(audioOptions);
      const options = {
        mimeType: 'audio/webm',
        numberOfAudioChannels: 1,
        sampleRate: 16000,
      };
      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(audioStream, options);
      console.log('Audio Status: ', mediaRecorder.state); 
      const chunks: any = [];
      if (this.micIcon === 'mic') {
        mediaRecorder.start();
        console.log('Audio Status: ', mediaRecorder.state); // This prints 'Recording'
      } else {
        console.log('Audio Status: ', mediaRecorder.state); // This prints 'Inactive'
        setTimeout(() => {
            const tracks = audioStream.getTracks();
            tracks.forEach((track: any) => {
            track.stop();
            mediaRecorder.stop();  // Getting the following error: ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'stop' on 'MediaRecorder': The MediaRecorder's state is 'inactive'.
          });
          },
          5000);
        console.log('Audio Status: ', mediaRecorder.state);
      }
      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e: any) => {
        chunks.push(e.data);
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/webm'});
        this.audioBlob = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log('Audio: ', this.audioBlob, chunks);
      };
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error: ', e);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I'm able to make sense of your code... is the `try` bloc executed several times? Does your code ever gets into the `else{}` after `if (this.micIcon === 'mic') {}`? If so, no wonder it fails here, `mediaRecorder` is a fresh new MediaRecorder instance that has never been started.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, you are right. Whenever user toggles the mic icon, a new instance of `mediaRecorder` is created, that's why it failed. Thank you for pointing out the flaw. You made my day!

Answer (score 2):

Try to set videoBitsPerSecond as 2500000 at options. It worked for me. Because the BPS was too high at first.